# Send string from js to node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I need to send a string from a .js, to my socket_server.js (node) which sends this string to a python server.

This is the code:

nao.js:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1');
socket.emit('comandos', pattern);
```

(pattern is the string)

socket_server.js:

```
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(8585, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
    console.log('Connected');
});

client.on('comandos', function(data) { //Recibe del .js
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.write(data); //Envía a .py
});
```

python server:

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8585
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2)

#APP
conn1, addr1 = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr1
#SERV
#conn2, addr2 = s.accept()
#print 'Connected by', addr2

while 1:
    try:
        data = conn1.recv(1024)
        print data
    except socket.error:
        print ''
    #if data:
        #print data.decode('utf-8')
        #conn2.send('lalala')
```

Python receives without problems the 'Hello, server! Love, Client.', but I need that Node (socket_server.js) receive the string that I want to send to python from nao.js.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Your `socket_server.js` will have to listen for websockets. Or you can remove the middleman and make use of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client and nao.js can talk to python directly.

Comment: So, you suggest me that change my python server and use socketIO-client, but I not sure how because in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client I cant see how to receive data, I only see emit, on, off and wait functions.

Comment: That was the client. See this link for how to write the server: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-socketio

Comment: This is what I receive in the python server from de JS: // (5650) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:8484 //
(5650) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 59513) //
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2016 19:37:50] "GET /socket.io/1/?t=1472405870036 HTTP/1.1" 200 401 0.000400 // This is what I have in JS:   var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8484'); //
  socket.emit('comandos', patronReconocido); // And in Python I have the example of pypi.python.org/pypi/python-socketio with some changes.